How to change a source in response to socket IO event? JS + Socket IO + Node js?
I'm trying to make a simple online game. When one player clicks on an object, the background picture changes, and I want to change it with css for all the connected players.
I was first doing it with
this.map.element.style.backgroundImage = `url('${newSrc}')`;

This worked only for the player who was doing the action. For all the other players the element's backgroundImage attribute changed (socket set correctly), however, the picture itself remained the same.
I found the thread that was solving the kind of similar issue (How to change image src after set by socket.io event?) and updated my code to the following:
let newElement = this.map.element;
newElement.style.backgroundImage = `url('${newSrc}')`
this.map.element.parentNode.replaceChild(this.map.element, newElement)

However, the result was the same. The last thing I tried was to reload the map from scratch as creating a brand new element, not copying this.map.element. I checked that the previous element is really being deleted, but I also found out that the new element for some reason is with the same pic. Even though in the developers' tools, I see that the URL is different.
What am I doing wrongly?

This has to be done on the client, not the server. The server needs to send a message to all the clients, telling them to change the image source.

@Barmar I'm doing it on the client side when the event is received through the server

The server needs to send the event to all the clients, so they'll each update their image URL.

That's what the server does, and I checked that other clients receive the event. However, the picture does not change. I marked it in the post: For all the other players the element's backgroundImage attribute changed (socket set correctly).

I found out that the problem was in cache. Cache busting helped. The code is somewhat like url('${newSrc + '?t=123456789'}') now.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This would only be an issue if the URL stays the same but the image file changes.
